# UIImageView's image takes up to 10 seconds to load

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a problem with my Swift code. I want to load a local image into an ImageView. This works fine. But when I simulate the app, you can only see the image after 10-15 seconds and I can't find the problem.

Here the code for the image:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "simple_weather_icon_01");

weatherIcon.image = image;

self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
```

Edit:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    get_data_from_url("myURL")
}

func get_data_from_url(url:String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler: {response, data, error in
            if data!.length > 0 && error == nil {
                let json = NSString(data: data!, encoding:  
                NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                self.extract_json(json!)
            } else if data!.length == 0 && error == nil {
                print("Nothing was downloaded1")
            } else if error != nil {
                print("Error happened = \(error)")
            }
        }
    )
}


func extract_json(data:NSString) {
    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    do {
        let json: NSDictionary! = try 
        NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: 
        .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

        let result = (json["weather"] as! [[NSObject:AnyObject]])[0]

        let aktIcon = result["icon"] as! String

        if aktIcon == "01d"{
            let image = UIImage(named: "simple_weather_icon_01");

            weatherIcon.image = image;

            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

            UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, 
            .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.weatherIcon.transform = 
                CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 
                180.0)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {

    }
}
```

Do I have to do something with the image?

Comment: Where is that code written? in what method? On what thread?

Comment: I added some Code. Hope it is al little bit better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you do a lot of UI-related code outside the UI thread (on some arbitrary callback thread) meaning that the UI-changes will not take effect immediately but rather at some later point in time (not clearly defined).

What you have to do is execute the UI-related code on the main thread via:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    // your ui code here
})
```

You can either execute the entire `extract_json` on the main thread or alternatively only the relevant code. The second option is probably better because it causes a little less load on the main thread.

### 1. the entire extract_json

You have to replace `self.extract_json(json!)` with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    extract_json(json!)
})
```

### 2. only the UI-code:

wrap the UI-code like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    let image = UIImage(named: "simple_weather_icon_01");

    weatherIcon.image = image;

    self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, 
        .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.weatherIcon.transform = 
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 
            180.0)
    }, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: Wow thanks!!! That worked absolutely perfect! But I don't really understand, why I have to do this.. :/ Can you explain this for me?

Comment: @mark96 there is one UI/main-Thread on iOS. ui changes have to be made in that thread, period. Changes made outside that thread may be taken into account only if the system decides to query for UI changes. Executing the code on the main thread will force iOS to update its UI. Thats the easy version, if you want to understand it in more detail, google for "ios main thread", "ios ui thread", etc.

Comment: @mark96 - when you call NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest, everything in the block gets executed in a background thread instead of the main thread.  That's why you have to make a call to move anything dealing with the UI back to the main thread.

Comment: Sorry about the edit, rolled it back after i realized this used swift syntax.